# How to auto redirect link with node/id to /name?

Tags: 7, redirection

I'm using [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) to generates all node url. There are many pages and blocks containing links with "node/id" instead of the "urlpath". When user click one of those link, it actually direct to the "node/id", not "urlpath" generated by Pathauto. How can I fix this?

PS: I dont wanna use "[Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect)" and add them one by one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect). That module does what you want it to do, it checks to see if there is a path alias for things like node/1 and if there is it will redirect to that URL.

> GlobalRedirect is a simple module which…
>
> 1. Checks the current URL for an alias and does a 301 redirect to it if it is not being used.
> 2. Checks the current URL for a trailing slash, removes it if present and repeats check 1 with the new request.
> 3. Checks if the current URL is the same as the site_frontpage and redirects to the frontpage if there is a match.
> 4. Checks if the Clean URLs feature is enabled and then checks the current URL is being accessed using the clean method rather than the 'unclean' method.
> 5. Checks access to the URL. If the user does not have access to the path, then no redirects are done. This helps avoid exposing private aliased node's.
> 6. Make sure the case of the URL being accessed is the same as the one set by the author/administrator. For example, if you set the alias "articles/cake-making" to node/123, then the user can access the alias with any combination of case.
>
> Most of the above options are configurable in the settings page. In Drupal 5 you can access this after enabling the globalredirect_admin module. In Drupal 6, the settings page is bundled into the module.

**Note**: That is straight from the module page, they haven't updated that Drupal 5-6 statement to include D7 I don't guess but I use this module in D7 and it works also.

Comment: That does exactly what I want, ty